# how to connect directly to VS 2022 iis express dot net 6 Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express, .net-6.0

before in dot net core there was xml file ".vs\config\applicationhost.config" and tag

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*" />
```

by change **bindingInformation** to "*" and run vs **as administrator**, I could connect to vs api directly by external devices and debug
but in dot net 6 that file not exists!

Comment: The file path changed since VS2019, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file